# in gulp command i get error in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, material-design

**if i run gulp serve to run project i have error like this so please help me because i am new in angular in localhost run properly but in c panel i have this issue**

```
Error: spawn EACCES
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:313:11)
at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:380:9)
at module.exports (/home/dothmobi/public_html/demo/drivzi_admin/materialadmin/material/node_modules/opn/index.js:75:24)
at Object.open (/home/dothmobi/public_html/demo/drivzi_admin/materialadmin/material/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/utils.js:186:9)
at Object.openBrowser (/home/dothmobi/public_html/demo/drivzi_admin/materialadmin/material/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/utils.js:165:23)
at EventEmitter.service:running (/home/dothmobi/public_html/demo/drivzi_admin/materialadmin/material/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/internal-events.js:42:23)
at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:188:7)
at /home/dothmobi/public_html/demo/drivzi_admin/materialadmin/material/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/browser-sync.js:260:19
```

[image: in this image i fire gulp serve command]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005867/gulp-error-spawn-eacces